# Do properties in linear algebra proved by using matrix transformations hold true irrespective of the choice of the bases for the vector spaces?

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations, vector-space-isomorphism

Let us say I am required to prove that V (dimension $= n$) and $\Bbb{R} ^ n$ are isomorphic and have chosen the matrix representation way of doing this.

Assume a linear transformation of

$T :V \rightarrow \Bbb{R} ^n$ that is injective.

The matrix representation is going to be a square matrix and as injectivity implies that the rank of $[T]$ is the dimension of $V$ ($= n$) which in turn means that the matrix is full rank. The rank of $[T]$ will also be equal to the dimension of the domain space and thus it is onto.

I think using this method I have proved that there exists a $T$ such that it is both injective and onto.

My only problem is that the $[T]$ here comes from fixing an ordered basis and I think the proof holds true only for these bases. How can I be sure that changing the basis would keep the proof intact?

PS: If the proof is wrong please include that too in the answer.

Comment: You haven't define any $T$ here. Then you are saying that you have proved there exists.... How? "$T$ comes from fixing the basis"??? Please write the question properly.

Comment: I have defined $T$ to be an injective linear transformation from $V$ to $\Bbb{R}^n$. And then I went on to prove that it is onto also.

Comment: Ok, then "$T$ comes from fixing..." explain what is this?

Comment: @A.Sharma Obtaining a matrix of the representation requires that we select ("fix") an ordered basis.

Comment: A change of basis is an isomorphism itself. Thus the rank of the representation matrix is invariant under a change of basis.

Comment: @A.Sharma $T$ is a matrix representation that comes from fixing ordered bases for both the V and $\Bbb{R}^n$. I honestly don't know how to explain this further.

Comment: @RajeshSri Can you try to elaborate on what you man by "the proof holds true only for these bases"? Remember that our goal is to show that there exists at least one invertible linear transformation $T:V \to \Bbb R^n$.

Comment: @RajeshSri It is problematic that you use $T$ to refer both to the matrix representation of a transformation and to the transformation itself.

Comment: Yes, you have written $T$ comes from fixing ordered basis. You should have written matrix of $T$ comes from...

Comment: The proof is done by assuming a fixed basis for getting a particular $T$ right? Let the bases fixed be $B_1$ and $B_2$ respectively. Using this you proved the isomorphism. Now if I change the bases to something else will the proof still hold.

Comment: @RajeshSri The reason that the proof works is that the basis contains $n$ elements. The [dimension theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dimension_theorem_for_vector_spaces) tells us that this property holds for every basis of $V$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no problem in proving something with the use of a basis, because a finite dimensional space does have one.

What's $[T]$? If we assume to take the canonical basis for the codomain, the columns of $[T]$ are precisely the vectors $T(v_1),T(v_2),\dots,T(v_n)$, where $\{v_1,v_2,\dots,v_n\}$ is the chosen basis.

Note that $\{w_1=T(v_1),w_2=T(v_2),w_n\dots,T(v_n)\}$ is also a basis of $\mathbb{R}^n$, because the set is linearly independent, due to $T$ being injective. So we can define a linear map $S\colon\mathbb{R}^n\to V$ by declaring that
$$
S(w_i)=v_i,\qquad i=1,2,\dots,n
$$
This map is the inverse of $T$: can you see it? So you actually don't need to use $[T]$ at all. Nor you need that the codomain is $\mathbb{R}^n$: it can be any $n$-dimensional vector space.

But you *must* use bases, because for infinite dimensional spaces it's false that injectivity implies surjectivity.